# Use css rules of pseudo class inside another pseudo class in less

Tags: css, less, extends, dynamically-generated, pseudo-class

I searched on the internet a solution to my issue with no results.

Here is the existent :

File A (which is a generated file so the content can change):

```
.icon-foo:before {
/* some css rules who can change at each generation*/
}
```

File B :

```
.mytag:after {

}
```

I want to include the rules of .icon-foo:before inside .mytag:after .
I saw on the internet that we cannot use pseudo class as mixins but that we can use extends to achieve his ends .

I tried some solutions but it didn't work.

I.e I tried :

```
.mytag {
    &:after:extend(.icon-foo:before){
    }
}
```

But nothing works.

Comment: Those are pseudo-*elements* not pseudo-classes.

Comment: Well, your code is correct (except it usually recommended to *not* use nesting w/o a reason, i.e. do not turn `.mytag:after {}` into `.mytag { &:after {}}` if you don't *have* to). So if "it's not working" you need to provide more details (how you compile these files, what compiler you use, how do you test if the result is valid or not and so on).

Comment: I use lessphp 0.3.9 and this it not working because the rule is not appearing on my css file.

Comment: It seems that this is due to lessphp.
I tried to use http://leafo.net/lessphp/ with the code below and it does not show the css rule.
.icon-foo:before {
    content: "toto";
}

.mytag:after:extend(.icon-foo:before){
}